# Sound isn’t working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, input, output

Sound isn't working in Ubuntu 18.04. I can't see any options under the input and output tabs in Settings -> *Sound*.

[image: blank screen in sound options]

What can I do to get my hardware to show up and be recognized in sound settings? How do I know if my hardware is compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: YELLING makes the audio even worse.  Once you fix the yelling, it would be helpful if you [edit] your answer and give details about your computer and its audio system.

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo alsa force-reload   
sudo reboot
```

If the input sound still doesn't work, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove alsa-base pulseaudio  
sudo apt purge alsa-base pulseaudio  
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload  
sudo reboot
```

If the input sound still doesn't work, go to your home directory and then go to the hidden config directory. Rename the directory named pulse here:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.bak  
sudo reboot
```